# how to port zmq to VxWorks?

Tags: zeromq, vxworks

I’ve done some searching but can’t find anyone who has ported zmq to VxWorks.
Does anyone have any advice how to do it, or has even one already port zmq to VxWorks?

Answer (score 0):

This mailing list thread http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2011-July/012609.html suggests that someone has ported it in the past, to vxworks 6.1.

The post suggests using ZMQ_HAVE_OPENVMS as a starting point.

VxWorks supports (mostly) POSIX calls, so it should in theory be possible.